# Media Stream and Capture API for creating mp4 from canvas elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mp4, mediastream

I have a serverless Vue SPA which creates GIF files completely client side. I wish to use the [Media Stream and Capture API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API) to create an mp4 instead. I am not sure how to setup the `Media Stream` ,along with frames per second and output filename, to accept my canvas elements one by one and how to export the resulting viedo file using `createObjectURL`. I currently `addFrame` once a map is rendered and a canvas element is drawn, but I am not sure how to connect this to the `ondataavailable` of a `MediaRecorder`. Can someone explain to me how this works please?

```js
async createGIFHandler ( layer , addAllTitles , quality , delay , range ) {
    ...
    var tempGIF = new GIF({
        workers: 4,
        quality: quality,
        height: this.mapHeight + this.infoCanvas.height,
        width: this.mapWidth,
        workerScript: 'gif.worker.js'
    });
    let progressCounter = 1;
    for ( let i = range[0] ; i < range[1] ; i++, progressCounter++ ) {
        this.setDateTime( driver , driverDA[i] );
        for ( let j = 0 ; j < visibleLayers.length ; j++ ) {
            if ( visibleLayers[j].get('layerName') !== layer.Name  ) {
                var tempDA = visibleLayers[j].get('layerDateArray');
                for ( let k = 0 ; k < tempDA.length ; k++ ) {
                    if ( driverDA[i].getTime() === tempDA[k].getTime() ) {
                        this.setDateTime( visibleLayers[j] , tempDA[k] );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        await new Promise(resolve => this.map.once('rendercomplete', resolve));
        await this.composeCanvas( tempGIF , driverDA[i] , visibleLayers , delay , widths )
        this.$store.dispatch('Layers/setGIFPercent', Math.round(((progressCounter / gifLength) * 100)))
    }

    tempGIF.on('finished', (blob) => {
        const tempURL = URL.createObjectURL( blob )
        this.$store.dispatch( 'Layers/setGIFURL' , tempURL )
        console.log('GIF Finished');
    });
    tempGIF.render();
},
async composeCanvas( gif , timeStep , visibleLayers , delayInput , widths ) {
    const mapCnv = this.getMapCanvas();
    await this.updateInfoCanvas( timeStep , widths )
    const composedCnv = await this.stitchCanvases( mapCnv , visibleLayers.length );
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
        gif.addFrame(composedCnv, { delay: delayInput });
        resolve();
    })
},
```

Comment: See if this helps you to setup your MediaRecorder object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API. PS: You need to encode video as H.264 picture format (codec) for using in MP4. If you see tutorials putting VP9 codec in MP4 or H.264 codec in WebM then avoid that since it will give issues on browser playback. Other MP4 encoding options include finding and using a JS-based H.264/MP4 encoder.